# Merge staging repository bare repository after push via hooks (GIT, Windows, GitStack)

Tags: windows, git, git-merge, githooks, gitstack

I have installed GitStack on Windows Server 2008, and for a given project created a bare repository to which I push from my local development environment.  I'd like to set up a hook that causes my staging environment to merge the pushed changes automatically on every push.

I'd posted a previous bash script but have now updated this to the below:

```
#!/bin/sh
export GIT_WORK_TREE=F:\\inetpub\\project_name\\staging\\
export GIT_DIR=F:\\inetpub\\project_name\\staging\\.git
git pull origin master
```

And get the following error message:

remote: bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!
remote: From F:/GitStack/repositories/project_name
remote:  * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
remote: error: unable to create directory for f:/inetpub/project_name/staging/.git/refs/remotes/origin/master
remote:  ! c8f4278..80cbe73  master     -> origin/master  (unable to update local ref)
To http://me@mydomain.com:9999/project_name.git
   c8f4278..80cbe73  master -> master
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'

I'm not sure where to go from here - any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the GitStack service as an Administrator.